# Laravel 4 view not randering

Tags: view, laravel-4

I have a project where all the views that are called from / (root) renders correctly like so

```
Route::get('link', 'SpecificController@myFunction'); //myFunction renders the view
```

I have added a directory and wildcard route so that I can manage many unknown urls like so

```
Route::get('directory/{anylink?}', function($anylink)
{   
    directoryController::directoryFunction($anylink);
});
```

That route and controller directoryFunction works fine. However, when directoryFunction renders the view, it's a blank page. It renders any other views just fine (and the problematic one) if not getting called by /directory/link but by /link

Also, in the controller I tried this

```
return View::make('good-name'); //return blank page

return View::make('bad-name'); //return error not found

return View::make('directory/good-name'); //return blank page

return View::make('directory/bad-name'); //return error not found
```

Result is the same if I put the view either in the views folder or in views/directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A view will not render if it has an error, it may raise an exception or not. Check for the error in your log files (Laravel and Apache or the webserver you're using).

Comment: I double checked, I confirm the view has no error

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it fixed. It seems like you can't render a view when a function is calling another function to render a view. So I replaced

```
Route::get('directory/{anylink?}', function($anylink)
{   
    directoryController::directoryFunction($anylink);
});
```

by

```
Route::get('directory/{anylink?}', 'directoryController@directoryFunction');
```